# How to make MergeBarcode fail gracefully when field is empty?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm working on a label printing job in MS Word, where some of the labels should have QR codes, and some do not.

When the field is empty, MERGEBARCODE generates an error message "Data length is not supported". I would prefer if it just showed up blank.

Currently I have `{ MERGEBARCODE field_name QR \s 50 }`

I've tried several attempts to wrap it in an IF, but MERGEBARCODE doesn't seem to work nested like that.
e.g.

`{ IF { MERGEFIELD field_name } = "" "" { MERGEBARCODE field_name QR \s 50 } }`

`{ IF field_name = "" "" { MERGEBARCODE field_name QR \s 50 } }`

`{ IF "{ MERGEFIELD field_name }" = "" "" { MERGEBARCODE field_name QR \s 50 } }`

All of these fail to generate a QR code. I'm new to word merge codes, so it's possible I'm misunderstanding the IF code somehow. I tested IF behavior without a QR code, and it can distinguish an empty field correctly.

The \b switch trick doesn't work with MERGEBARCODE.

Looking for a way to fail smoothly when only some QR codes are present.

Answer (score 1):

I can produce your issue.

It seems that we not use If field to hide the "Data length is not supported by current type." when barcode value is empty.

Based on my tests, please check whether the following fields formula is helpful.

`{IF"{MergeField Barcode}"<>"" "{Set X {MergeField Barcode}}"}{DisplayBarcode"{X}" QR \s 50 ""}`

If the barcode value is empty, it will creates a specified QR code. Please check the
N0.4 QR code on following gif.

[image]

Comment: Your code is still giving "Data length is not supported" for me :-(

Comment: I see how I could use your code to create a default QR code, but I really want to hide it if not populated.